# SQL: What is the syntax error in this Create View script? (Beginner)

Tags: mysql, sql, select, syntax, workbench

I am trying to create a new view, with two different queries. I am new to SQL and I'm wondering what is causing the syntax error for the following code:

```
CREATE VIEW `License_Expiration` AS

/* These queries show the license expiration date for retailers and 
processing facilities, sorted by soonest expiration date */

SELECT `Retailers`.`Retailer_Name`, `Retailers`.`Retail_License_Number`, 
`Retailers`.`Retal_License_Expiration` FROM `mydb2`.`Retailers`
ORDER BY `Retailers`.`Retal_License_Expiration`;

SELECT `Processing Facility`.`Facility_Name`, `Processing 
Facility`.`Facility_License_Num`, `Processing 
Facility`.`Facility_License_Exp` FROM `mydb2`.`Processing Facility`
ORDER BY `Processing Facility`.`Facility_License_Exp`;
```

The syntax error occurs at the second SELECT statement: "SELECT is not a valid input at this position". I am using SQL Workbench. Any help is appreciated!

EDIT:
your solutions have solved it, thanks for your help!!

Comment: Have you tried removing the 1st `SELECT` and see if the 2nd `SELECT` works or still would give an error? Also I don't think you could return two SELECT results in a view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot create a view with two independent SELECT statements as you have done.  According to the MySQL 5.7 documentation, the syntax for a view is as shown below.

```
CREATE
    [OR REPLACE]
    [ALGORITHM = {UNDEFINED | MERGE | TEMPTABLE}]
    [DEFINER = { user | CURRENT_USER }]
    [SQL SECURITY { DEFINER | INVOKER }]
    VIEW view_name [(column_list)]
    AS select_statement
    [WITH [CASCADED | LOCAL] CHECK OPTION]
```

Since it appears you want to get license expiration from two types - namely, retailers and facilities - perhaps you could UNION these two SELECT statements and have a CHAR column that indicates if the record is for a retailer or facility.  The UNION assumes that all columns are of the same type.

```
CREATE VIEW `License_Expiration` AS

    /* These queries show the license expiration date for retailers and 
    processing facilities, sorted by soonest expiration date */

    (SELECT `Retailers`.`Retailer_Name`, AS Name,
    `Retailers`.`Retail_License_Number` AS License_Number,
    `Retailers`.`Retal_License_Expiration` AS License_Expiration, 'R'   
    AS Source_Type FROM `mydb2`.`Retailers`)

    UNION

    (SELECT `Processing Facility`.`Facility_Name`, AS Name, 
    `Processing Facility`.`Facility_License_Num` AS License_Number,     
    `Processing Facility`.`Facility_License_Exp` AS License_Expiration,  
    'F' AS Source_Type FROM `mydb2`.`Processing Facility`)

    ORDER BY Name, License Expiration;
```

Hope this helps.  Give it a shot.

Answer (score 1):

As  I Think  you can't get  more  than one selection within the  query  to  create  a  view.  If  still you want all the  columns of  the two  selections , please  join these  two tables  and create  view with necessary  columns or  you can  have  an union  according  to the  requirement .

Answer (score 0):

You could either create **two** `Views` like:

```
CREATE VIEW `License_Expiration_Retailer` AS

/* These queries show the license expiration date for retailers and 
   processing facilities, sorted by soonest expiration date */

SELECT `Retailers`.`Retailer_Name`, 
`Retailers`.`Retail_License_Number`, 
`Retailers`.`Retal_License_Expiration` FROM `mydb2`.`Retailers`
ORDER BY `Retailers`.`Retal_License_Expiration`;


CREATE VIEW `License_Expiration_Processing_Facilities` AS

SELECT `Processing Facility`.`Facility_Name`, `Processing 
Facility`.`Facility_License_Num`, `Processing 
Facility`.`Facility_License_Exp` FROM `mydb2`.`Processing Facility`
ORDER BY `Processing Facility`.`Facility_License_Exp`;
```

Or **one** `View` merging the two:

```
CREATE VIEW `License_Expiration` AS

/* These queries show the license expiration date for retailers and 
   processing facilities, sorted by soonest expiration date */

SELECT "Retailer" as License_Type, `Retailers`.`Retailer_Name` as Owner_Name, 
`Retailers`.`Retail_License_Number` as License_Number, 
`Retailers`.`Retal_License_Expiration` as Lincense_Expiration_Date FROM `mydb2`.`Retailers`
ORDER BY `Retailers`.`Retal_License_Expiration`;

UNION ALL

SELECT "Processing Facility" as License_Type, 
`Processing Facility`.`Facility_Name` as OwnerName, `Processing 
Facility`.`Facility_License_Num` as License_Number, `Processing 
Facility`.`Facility_License_Exp` as Lincense_Expiration_Date 
FROM `mydb2`.`Processing Facility`
ORDER BY `Processing Facility`.`Facility_License_Exp`;
```